# Monitor.Enter(object,ref bool) Implementation and Order of Lock Acquisition

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, race-condition

From [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs,5d517f5a97464e27) we can see that the aforementioned method is implemented as follows:

```
 public static void Enter(Object obj, ref bool lockTaken)
    {
        if (lockTaken)
            ThrowLockTakenException();

        ReliableEnter(obj, ref lockTaken);
        Contract.Assert(lockTaken);
    }
```

I have an issue is with the 'if' statement- I understand it's importance, there's no need to explain that. I believe this statement also introduces a very subtle issue.

Consider the following scenario:
One thread calls into the method and evaluates the if statement, at which point a context switch occurs and another calls into the method, successfully obtaining the lock.

This is a feasible scenario which suggests that the order of lock acquisition is not necessarily the same as the order of method invocation.

While it may not really make a difference in some scenarios, it could be of critical importance in others, so my questions are:

1) Am I missing something, or is the Monitor class less suited for use in scenarios where such occurrences are unacceptable?

2) Is it possible that ReliableEnter suffers from a similar condition?

3)Is there a synchronization mechanism which ensures that the order of method invocation is the same as the order of lock acquisition?

Comment: `of critical importance in others` which ones? A method invocation is not observable so it does not matter when Enter and ReliableEnter are called. Nobody can tell. What matters is the actual lock *acquisition*.

Comment: I wonder why you referenced the `if` statement at all in your question since it seems immaterial to points 1-3. Are you worried about a data race? Each thread is supposed to reference a different boolean variable with `lockTaken` so there is no data race.

Comment: For example, a video camera driver which emits a frame at a time, on a newly started thread. Silly, I know, but still.. we do not always control every aspect of our program. @usr

Comment: @usr Ofcourse that there's no data race in regard to the boolean variable. I referenced it to point out if (and only if) the ReliableEnter method did ipmose "order of invocation is the order of acquisition" - then the time which takes to evaluate the if statement would violate this promise.

Comment: Yes, it does violate this property (=> the property does not hold). But if the runtime magically made the property hold nobody would be able to tell since *method invocations are not observable*. It cannot possibly matter. This is independent of the program.

Comment: @usr I know this now, thank's to Eric's answers and your comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> One thread calls into the method and evaluates the if statement, at which point a context switch occurs and another calls into the method, successfully obtaining the lock.

That's totally possible.

Or, there might be no context switch but this still happens. Two threads both get past the "if" and into ReliableEnter, there's no context switch on either, and one wins. Can you think of a scenario in which that happens?

> This is a feasible scenario which suggests that the order of lock acquisition is not necessarily the same as the order of method invocation.

Remember the story of the three umpires.

Three umpires are having lunch. The first says "I calls them as I sees them".  The second says "I calls them as they are".  The third says "They ain't nothing until I calls them."

The first umpire believes that observation is imperfect and that people can disagree as to whether a pitch is a ball or a strike. The second believes that there is a consistent physical world and they have accurate information about it; whether a pitch is a ball or a strike can be determined objectively. The third believes that irrespective of whether the world is consistent and knowable, *the rules of baseball say that a strike is anything that the umpire calls a strike*.

You're the second umpire. You think there actually is such a thing as "the order in which method calls occur" in a multithreaded world, and that there is a way to know about it.  But really the world is more like the first umpire: everyone can see a different world and disagree on it.  And locks are more like the third umpire: **locks are the things that impose an ordering upon an unordered world**. What order were the methods called in? **Take a lock and find out**.

Abandon the myth that there is a consistent order in which things happen in the multithreaded world. **There is no such consistent order**. Every processor can reorder code as much as it wants within the memory model constraints. Every thread can see a different ordering of reads and writes.

What every thread agrees on is the order in which locks are taken, so that is the sensible thing to consider "the order" in which methods are called.

So, can locks happen in a different order than method calls?  The first umpire says "no one can know for sure". The second says "yes". The third says "there is no order at all *until a lock is taken*".

I agree with the third umpire. Can a lock be taken in a different order than the methods were called?  Since *the only way to impose that order is to take a lock*, it's not really a sensible question.

> 1) Am I missing something, or is the Monitor class less suited for use in scenarios where such occurrences are unacceptable?

That's the wrong way to look at it.

If we continue believing the fiction that there is an order in which calls happen, and you have a program which depends for its correctness upon locks being taken in that entirely mythological order, then that program has a bug. Locks are *not* taken in "the order that the calls happen", end of story, and if you depend on that, then you're depending on a guarantee made by no one and often violated.

> 2) Is it possible that ReliableEnter suffers from a similar condition?

I don't understand the question. Do you mean, if we replaced every call to `Enter` with a call to `ReliableEnter`, would we still have the same issue? Yes, absolutely.

> 3)Is there a synchronization mechanism which ensures that the order of method invocation is the same as the order of lock acquisition?

There is no such order independent of locks, so no.

> I have an issue is with the 'if' statement- I understand it's importance, there's no need to explain that. I believe this statement also introduces a very subtle issue.

Your belief is wrong. The issue is introduced by the fact that there is no such thing as "the order in which method calls happen" in a multithreaded world. The "if" has nothing whatsoever to do with it.

Moreover, even in a world where we *can* extract ordering information from a lock, *locks are not guaranteed to be fair*.  If you have ten threads all waiting on a lock there is no requirement imposed by the C# language that the thread that has been "waiting longest" or "called first" -- whatever that means -- is the one who gets access to the monitor next. The operating system has broad latitude to schedule threads as it sees fit, and it is within its rights to starve a thread indefinitely.

Now, there are many half-truths in what I've said above. The actual state of the world is very confusing. If you want to know the truth then you should read the section of the C# specification about *ordering of side effects in multithreaded programs*, which describes the events which are guaranteed to be observed to be in particular orders: locks, creations of threads, certain kinds of reads and writes, exceptions and constructor calls. The ordering guarantees are in some cases very weak.

As I always do when this comes up, I recommend that you read my article on how reorderings can happen in a world without locks. See if you can solve the puzzle I pose in the second part.

http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer/
http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for a very elaborate answer. 
Second- color me educated as far as locking guarantees go.
As for your question ("Can you think of a scenario in which that happens?")- the answer is on a multi processor machine. I was merely providing a specific example in my question.

If by puzzle you mean the question regarding s and t, then I got it right :).

Apart from CLR via C# and the language specification, what source of information would you recommend for someone who would really like to know the nitty gritty details?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are describing is an actual problem. The if statement is not related to the state of the lock. It just serves as input validation to ensure the value of the second parameter is false.

Imagine the if-statement wasn't there. The context switch could still occur for example after the return address is pushed onto the stack and before the jump instruction is executed.

Locks serve to prevent the program from entering an inconsistent state. However, if the critical sections are structured correctly, the order of lock acquisition doesn't matter. In the example you described, the program will simply continue as if the second thread had aquired the lock and the first thread will have `false` in the lockTaken parameter.

Comment: Let's suppose that there's a system which processes information as it arrives, and that it has to ensure information is handled in the order of arrival.

The windows quantum is ~30 milliseconds, which means that
having some thread attempt to acquire a lock at the end of the quantum leaves quite a margin for error. A lot can happen is 30 milliseconds.

Comment: Either the arriving information contains some sequence number allowing the data to be processed in the desired order or the arrival order is given by the order in which threads acquire the lock. This is as good as it gets in a multitasking operating system.